# No WebGL on Android Webview in version 6.0

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, webgl, samsung-galaxy

I just bought the latest Samsung Galaxy S7 for the sole purpose of actually being able to use its WebView. If you didnt know paid Android developers have basically been screwing over the little guy by not allowing us to have the full Chrome WebView capabilities inside the Android developer WebView. Over the last few generations of Android they have been slowly releasing these features which shouldve been included in the first place, occasionally in sketchy/bulky platforms like Crosswalk. This is the third device I am trying and is brand new and still cant do it.

I have tried:
Upgrading my device (it's Android 6.0)

Updating Android WebView from the Play Store

Testing in Chrome Browser (my website loads with WebGL here)

Testing in Chrome Browser for Android (my website loads with WebGL here)

Testing inside an Android webview inside my app (my website fails and says WebGL is not supported)

Implementing Crosswalk (Wont be embedded in an existing android application without forcing user to download separate app. Is bloaty and fragile)

Unfortunately there is not much documentation on this and if you look at other answers devices are really spotty on whether they have it, but almost all phones after Android L are supposed to. This is a full version later. How could they just not include it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This month's patch actually fixed everything.  Just download a system update if you're on an S7. Thanks to whoever filed the bug report.